# Add a hidden datetime field in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7, wordpress-shortcode

I'm using contact form 7 in wordpress.

I have several fields and I want to send one hidden field with a date and time of the server where the wordpress is hosted.

I have used:

```
[hidden  date your-date ]
```

I have added:

```
<input type="hidden" name="your-date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); ?>">
```

In this case I get a forbidden message when trying to send.

Is there a way to do this or is not possible using these tools???

thanks